# Why no argument for cache() function in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am learning Spark by apply some basic handson.

The below code works.

```
val fileRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/words.txt")
val cacheRDD = fileRDD.cache()
```

But I would like to know that Does cache() function is part of ACTION or TRANSFORMATION?

Also Can we supply arguments to cache() function ?

I also tried the below code .

```
val cacheRDD = fileRDD.cache(org.apache.spark.storage.DISK_ONLY)
```

but I get below error when i supplied above argument

```
 too many arguments for method cache :()fileRDD.type
```

What do i need to do if i want to supply argument that tells the StorageLevel to Cache() function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive you are looking for persist.

```
fileRdd.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

Comment: So syntax wise Cache() function does not  allow arguments?

Comment: cache() just persist the RDD with default storage level (`MEMORY_ONLY`)

Comment: Neither. When an action is called, this part of the transformations will be cached.

Comment: Ok. Thanks  much for your help